# compare two files based upon the partial same string and output the same content

Tags: batch-file

I have two files

first file looks like this:

```
500006011000.S3S.mockup
500007011000.S3S.mockup
500008011000.S3S.mockup
500009011000.S3S.mockup
500010011000.S3S.mockup
500012011000.S3S.mockup
500014011000.S3S.mockup
500016011000.S3S.mockup
500134010100.S3S.mockup
500028011201.S3S.mockup
500129010200.S3S.mockup
500142010100.S3S.mockup
500144010100.S3S.mockup
500015011800.S3S.mockup
```

The second files looks

```
500006011000.S3S
500006011000.S3S
500007011000.S3S
500008011000.S3S
500009011000.S3S
500010011000.S3S
500011011000.S3S
500012011000.S3S
500014011000.S3S
500015011800.S3S
500016011000.S3S
500018011000.S3S
500022010400.S3S
500028011201.S3S
500031010200.S3S
500032030200.S3S
500040020500.S3S
500063011000.S3S
500067010001.S3S
500072010400.S3S
500099010300.S3S
500129010200.S3S
500134010100.S3S
500142010100.S3S
500144010100.S3S
500146010100.S3S
500147010100.S3S
Contents.lst
gen_sch_list.txt
```

I can use this code to compare then output the same content

```
findstr /ixg:C:\CA_MOCKUP\first.txt C:\CA_MOCKUP\second.txt > C:\CA_MOCKUP\result.txt
```

Normally it will work only if the first txt remove .mockup for each line.

Can we compare two file only based on the first 6 digits of the string which will accommodate a lot of issues that may arise in many circumstance.

Comment: At first, I'd try `findstr /B` instead of `findstr /X`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid your question is pretty confusing. `findstr` command does not *compare files*; it *find strings*. (BTW see `fc` command). Also, you didn't specified of which file you want "the same content"...

The code below *extracts* the lines from `first.txt` file whose first six characters also appear in the first six characters in *any line* of `second.txt` file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create the "key" array with the first six chars from second.txt file
for /F "delims=" %%a in (second.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   set "key[!line:~0,6!]=1"
)

rem Extract the lines in first.txt file with the same key
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (first.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   set "s6=!line:~0,6!"
   if defined key[!s6!] echo !line!
)) > result.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Aacini! After switched my two txt files, that is, my first.txt to be your second.txt and my second.txt to be your first.txt and run your code and got exactly what I want....

Comment: It really depends upon what kind of format of the string ending with either .s3s or .mockup as an input file, your code can have them all as long as I add one logic to detect the input file then determine which file as first and second file...

Answer (score 0):

For collecting only the first 6 characters of each line we can use some `for` loops along with [syntax-substring](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html). We can simply store this modified data in new temporary files to compare with `findstr` later on.

**CompareFirst6Chars.bat:**

```
@echo off
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Rem | Configuration
Set "CompaireFile1=1.txt"
Set "CompaireFile2=2.txt"
Set "ResultFile=result.txt

Rem | Loop For Each Item
for %%A in (!CompaireFile1! !CompaireFile2!) do (

    Rem | Grab Only First 6 Characters From Files, Format In Modified
    for /f "Tokens=*" %%B in (%%A) do (

        Rem | Save & Modify Strings
        Set "Modified=%%B"
        Set "Modified=!Modified:~0,6!"

        Rem | Save To File
        Echo !Modified!>> %%A.temp

    )
)

Rem | Compare & Extract Results
findstr /ixg:!CompaireFile1!.temp !CompaireFile2!.temp > !ResultFile!

Rem | Remove Temp Files
Del "!CompaireFile1!.temp" "!CompaireFile2!.temp"
goto :EOF
```

**This will give us an output of the following:**

```
500006
500006
500007
500008
500009
500010
500012
500014
500015
500016
500028
500129
500134
500142
500144
```

---

An alternitive solution is to completely remove the `.mockup` from the string. To do this, The process is very simular but instead of [syntax-substring](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) we use [syntax-replace](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html). This will let us replace all `.mockup` to nothing.

**RemoveMockupCompareFiles.bat:**

```
@echo off
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Rem | Configuration
Set "CompaireFile1=1.txt"
Set "CompaireFile2=2.txt"
Set "ResultFile=result.txt

Rem | Loop For Each Item
for %%A in (!CompaireFile1! !CompaireFile2!) do (

    Rem | Grab Only First 6 Characters From Files, Format In Modified
    for /f "Tokens=*" %%B in (%%A) do (

        Rem | Save & Modify Strings
        Set "Modified=%%B"
        Set "Modified=!Modified:.mockup=!"

        Rem | Save To File
        Echo !Modified!>> %%A.temp

    )
)

Rem | Compare & Extract Results
findstr /ixg:!CompaireFile1!.temp !CompaireFile2!.temp > !ResultFile!

Rem | Remove Temp Files
Del "!CompaireFile1!.temp" "!CompaireFile2!.temp"
goto :EOF
```

**This will give us an output of the following:**

```
500006011000.S3S
500006011000.S3S
500007011000.S3S
500008011000.S3S
500009011000.S3S
500010011000.S3S
500012011000.S3S
500014011000.S3S
500015011800.S3S
500016011000.S3S
500028011201.S3S
500129010200.S3S
500134010100.S3S
500142010100.S3S
500144010100.S3S
```

---

For help on any of the commands do the following:

- `call /?`
- `set /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `find /?`
- So on.